# how to pass a variable with the help of ajax jquery into a function directly, which is on another page

Tags: ajax

how to pass a variable with the help of ajax jquery into a function directly, which is on another page

```
function show_data2(str1) {

            xml2http = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xml2http.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (xml2http.readyState === 4 && xml2http.status === 200) {
                    document.getElementById("show_data_sal").innerHTML = xml2http.responseText;
                }
            };

            xml2http.open("POST", "functions.php?r=" + str1, true);
            xml2http.send(str1);
        };


functions.php


class querydb
{
function useHere()
{
...I want to use that variable 'r' here.
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery, this will be the easiest way to send post data via ajax:

```
var jqxhr = $.ajax( {
  method: "POST",
  url: "functions.php",
  data: { r: "some value", s: "another value" }
})
  .done(function() {
    alert( "success" );
  })
  .fail(function() {
    alert( "error" );
  })
  .always(function() {
    alert( "complete" );
  });
```

function.php

```
class querydb
{
  function useHere()
  {
    // We're sending our post data as json so we'll need php to decode it for us to use.
    $foo = json_decode($_POST[], true);
    // you can now access your variables like an array
    $bar = $foo['r'];
  }
}
```

Just be sure to clean anything from post before you do anything with it to prevent any malicious parameters coming through